# Incorrect format parameter

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Currently, when I visit `localhost/phpmyadmin`, I am seeing the following error:

> ERROR: Token Mismatch  (*In tooltip*)
>
> Incorrect format parameter

I will explain the changes I did step by step:

- I had xampp of version 1.7.1 installed.
- To upgrade it to latest, I renamed Xampp folder in `c://` to "xampp_1" and took the group database backup in `.sql` format.
- From this [link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/), I downloaded `php_oauth-1.2.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip` and copied the `php_oauth.dll` to `c://xampp/php/ext/` and then in `php.ini`, I mentioned `extension=php_oauth.dll`.
- After this, I ran Apache server and Mysql through Xampp.
  then tried to import the sql backup file through CLI as follows:

  ```
    mysql -u root < localhost.sql
  ```
- I got some error in command prompt. (*I will update this soon*)
- Then later when I visited `localhost/phpmyadmin`, I am seeing this page:

[image]

Comment: I uninstalled both 1.7.1 and 5.6.3 and then re-installed 5.6.3. That did the trick.

Comment: Just hit this('localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php') url will work(no query strings and extra parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding solution as a answer text so that the question drops from the Unanswered Questions list.  Original answer is provided by the question author in a reply/comment on his original question text:

> I uninstalled both 1.7.1 and 5.6.3 and then re-installed 5.6.3. That
>   did the trick.

Comment: this did not work for me, pulling latest stable phpmyadmin from git repo did fix my issues

Comment: this is not a solution, you didnt identify the problem.

Comment: I disagree. A solution fixes a problem. Sometimes a problem is fixed without identifying the cause of the problem. In this case, the person who asked the question had a problem. After performing the step quoted above, he no longer had the problem. Other people looking for answers on how to fix a similar problem now have this as an option knowing that it worked before in at least one case.

Answer (score 19):

In my case this worked:

1. logout
2. clear url (remove all after `?`, wspecially `token=blablabla` must be removed)
3. remove all cookies
4. refresh
5. login

This can't fix the problem basically as the same error may appear in any time

Comment: Just hit this('http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php') url will work(no query strings)

Comment: I just logged out of the phpmyadmin and relogged in !

Comment: This happened to me when the last action I performed before rebooting was an import.  The import command was still in the URL the next time I opened the browser and tried to login.

Answer (score 12):

Find php.ini in the xampp

- 1- `post_max_size: 128M` (give a size for example 128)
- 2- `upload_max_filesize : 64M` (for example 64)

`post_max_size` must be larger than `upload_max_filesize` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Reason:** You are getting this error because size of your filename.sql is greater than maximum upload limit. (By default you can import upto `Max:2,048KiB`)

**Solution:**

1. Navigate to `xampp\php\php.ini`
2. Find `upload_max_filesize` and increase it to desired upload side (e.g. `upload_max_filesize=128M`) and save
3. Restart `xampp`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the Post Maximum size, open the `PHP.ini` file and find the 
`post_max_size=8M` and increase it up to `post_max_size=128M`,

1.`PHP.ini` ->increase the `post_max_size` parameter from `8M` up to `128M`,

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a perfect solution in the following tool: 
[BigDump: Staggered MySQL Dump Importer](https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)

which allowed me to change the `connection charset` to match that of the dumpfile. Works fine without any installs/re-installs.

Answer (score 0):

1. set this database and ini file

SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
max_allowed_packet = 64M

2. then: use CLI (cmd)
   goto ->xamp->mysql->bin
   copy the path n set in Cmd
3. use below command to dumb db 
   mysql.exe -u root -p db_name< "C:\Users\path\file.sql"